# SoX will not run using "play". 'play' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: sox

I've already added `sox` to my PATH and it seems to be doing fine with that. If I open my terminal and enter `C:\Users\[EXAMPLE USERNAME]>sox`, the program will run through all of the options and effects. The problem is I can't seem to get `play` to work. I've tried `C:\Users\[EXAMPLE USERNAME]>play file.ogg` which gives the resulting error: `'play' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.

I would normally think to create a PATH variable for `play` but as mentioned in the comments of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122781/command-line-program-for-playing-sections-of-audio-specified-in-milliseconds#12122884), there is no executable, it's `sox` under a different name.

Also, for reference, I'm using sox-14-4-2 on Windows 10.

Comment: This isn’t really programming related, but did you try `sox file.ogg` like the comments say in the linked question?

Comment: @Samikuhmonen I'm assuming you mean `sox audio.wav -d trim START =END`, yes? `sox file.ogg` just results in `sox FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified`. `sox audio.wav -d trim START =END` results in `sox FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the comment in the linked question, it's mentioned that "`play` is `sox` just under a different name." I had interpreted this to mean `play` is a part of `sox`'s code, where you only needed one file: `sox` and, provided everything was properly configured, that file would be called on through the use of any of those commands (where the specific command would activate its specific code in `sox`). It turns out I over-complicated this a lot. The actual solution is copying `sox` a three times and renaming the duplicates to `play`, `rec` and `soxi`. The reason why they weren't included in the `.exe` was for space. I personally don't see why the developers couldn't have just gone the route of what I assumed to conserve space, but that's just my opinion on the matter.